# Is it okay to ask a question about how to use a specific plug-in here?

Tags: discussion, plugins

From the description of this stack it seems to me that specific questions about how to use particular plug ins would not be welcome.  Is this true?

If so, what are the idea places to ask these questions?

Comment: You are right, this stack isn't the right place for plug-in recommendation and plug-in usage questions. If you want to ask a plug-in related coding/development questions, it is best to do this in a manner that can be lead back to core functionality of WordPress, otherwise there is a great likelihood that the question will be deemed [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The ideal place I'd say is the support forum of the WordPress plug-in repository or if it's on github you can open an issue. If you paid for it, there should be support included.

Comment: Thanks for this thoughtful response.

Comment: My pleasure, especially because you are asking nicely and informed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, plugins are mostly considered not in scope, because such questions usually involve plugin's internals, not WordPress internals. Happens in WordPress context, but is not WordPress-specific.

The good places would be:

- whatever plugin itself documents places to be (support forum, issue tracker, etc)
- reaching out to plugin's developer (politely and without expectation they have to spent time replying)
- WP resources that are fine with such questions, I see Google+ communities on WP recommended often